# How to get the dynamic form key value in Jmeter when logging into Web Application

Tags: forms, authentication, web, jmeter

I have created a test plan, thread group , sample and listener. I don't know how to get the form key in Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Given you're asking a generic question you will get a generic answer: use a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors).

If you're talking about a [HTML Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp3) the most suitable would be [CSS Selector Extractor (was: CSS/JQuery Extractor )](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor)

Example:

[image]

More information:

- [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)
- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)